# Why is the Twitter API v-2 not giving me access?

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth, twitter-api-v2

I have been trying to access twitter's API. I only wanted to see trending news or just news but it is always giving me this error on Postman [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZR938.png).

I have tried a lot of the endpoints specified on Twitter's website for essential access. But I still get this error.

Answer (score 0):

Twitter API has restrictions based on your account type and it doesn't let you access those you don't have permission to. Try one of simple endpoints that is available for your account, which is Essential based on the message. And if there is still error then post it here.

And also make sure that to access Twitter API v2 your app needs to be connected to a Project, it should not b a standalone app. You can change this from
twitter developers portal.